# my ute wont start

Tags: ford, starting, starter, falcon

I drive a ford falcon au 2000 v8 ute. Drove my ute to the local shopping centre, about a 2 min drive & now it wont start. Ive got power on the dash, relays & fuses all look intact & got plenty of fuel. One thing that is noticeable is that the brakes are heavy and the steering hard to turn. Has anyone had the same problem or know of a fix? Cheers

Comment: Does the starter turn?  Are there any strange noises when it is trying to start?

Comment: If the engine is not running, it will be hard to turn the steering and press the brakes.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well if it doesn't start then of course steering and brakes are heavy. There is no universal "fix" for a non-starting vehicle. You'll have to provide more information.